# Sonata Page bundle - translator service not working

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I've started a symfony project and have installed Sonata admin and page bundle. The problem is that even though I have translator service enabled, I still get labels like `list.label_is_default` and `list.label_enabled` on the parts of the Admin from the Page bundle, wheres on other parts of the Admin the labels are correctly shown.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there were some changes not reflected in the documentation.

I needed to change parameter locale from `locale: en` to `locale: en_US`